# Swift- Adding Two UI Numbers then Output in Label

Tags: swift

I can do this in C++/C, Objective C and Playground. I cannot get this to work in Swift when I try to make the App.

Can someone help out please?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Simple Mathemtical Functions_Swift
//
//  Created by  on 7/01/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 . All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labelResult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Number2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Number1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var field1: [UITextField]!
    @IBOutlet var field2: [UITextField]!
    @IBAction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    labelResult.text = "\()"}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.\

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: How could this possibly work when you're setting `labelResult.text` to `"\()"` in your `Calculate` action?

Comment: I left it blank as my previous efforts were always errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `field1` and `field2` and just `UITextField`s then `[UITextField]!` should be changed to `UITextField!`. `[UITextField]` indicates an array of `UITextField`s.

```
@IBOutlet var labelResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Number2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Number1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var field1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var field2: UITextField!


@IBAction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject) {

    var a = (field1.text as NSString).floatValue
    var b = (field2.text as NSString).floatValue
    var sum = a + b
    labelResult.text = "\(sum)"

}
```

Comment: I just did that before your post, but now I have the following error-  'String' does not have a member named 'floatValue'. Wait a minute.

Comment: that is why i did `(field1.text as NSString).floatValue` in the code. note the `NSString`. it's not `String`.

Comment: Ok just tried to convert the string as float value and it worked, but now have many override errors in the code below.  I have no idea why that is happening.

Comment: can you show me the updated code? Did you use the same code as above?

Comment: I was missing some braces for the override function!  All the errors have gone and code works!  Thank you rakeshbs!  Brilliant!  Now I need to spend some time and understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're having trouble because `field1.text` is a `String?` not an `NSString`.

```
@IBAction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    labelResult.text = "\((field1.text as NSString).floatValue + (field2.text as NSString).floatValue)"
}
```